# Highstock : update xAxis events

Tags: events, highcharts

I am creating a chart with this method after setting my options

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
```

I keep `chart` in a variable cause I need to use it further to add a series :

```
chart.addSeries(chartSeries,true,false);
```

From this point. I want to update the event on my xAxis :

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
            events : {
                afterSetExtremes: function(){
                    //some stuff
                }
            }
});
```

But this has no effect. However, any other update works (like setting `type : 'normal'`)

Comment: try using afterSetExtremes: function(event) instead of afterSetExtremes: function()

Comment: sorry for the long time to answer. No it doesn't work by adding `event` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no effect.
You can try changing function like this - http://jsfiddle.net/a9wv3kd0/2/

```
var test = function(){
    console.log(1)
};

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function () {
                    test();
                }
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },

        navigator: {
            enabled: true
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'MSFT',
            data: MSFT
        }]
    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'ADBE',
            data: ADBE
        });
        test = function () {console.log(2)};
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```